# How to close the handle of tempfile.mkstemp?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to change the `def a` to close the handle that is opened by `mkstemp`. But I failed.

`handle.close()` leads to erros because handle is just an `int`...

`del handle` also does not change the behaviour

MWE:

```
import tempfile
import codecs 

def a(json_content):
    handle, file = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix="foobar-",suffix=".json")
    write_to_file(json_content, file)

def write_to_file(text, filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-8', errors='ignore') as fp:
        fp.write(unicode(text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(50000):
        a('{"foo":"bar", "iteration":%s}' %(i))
```

I use anaconda python 2.7.13 with windows (if thats making a difference)

Comment: definitely a dupe. damn. i searched but obviously, "handle" was the wrong term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`os.close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.close) to close a file represented by a file descriptor:

```
os.close(handle)
```